# How to remove specific object from cache on findAll method?

Tags: spring, caching, spring-data, ehcache

I  have findAll method that returns me all objects in DB and it is cached.
But when i update some object I want to update that element in cache.
But on findAll i don't know how to map with key:

```
 @Cacheable("findAllStudens")
 public Collection<StudensImpl> findAll()
```

When i update student I want to update cache but only for that element.
Does someone has same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the annotation @CachePut on your update method, like this:

```
@CachePut(cacheNames = "findAllStudens")
public void update(StudensImpl studensImpl) {
...
}
```

Comment: this is the way to update only that object in cache ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add @CacheEvict(“ findAllStudens”) annotation before your update method

CacheEvict annotation will delete the data from existing cache. And next time you call findAll() the code inside the method will be executed and the returned list will be stored on your cache

Comment: I have never use it but it seems that @CachePut are doing the job (Felipe answer)  http://websystique.com/spring/spring-4-cacheable-cacheput-cacheevict-caching-cacheconfig-enablecaching-tutorial/

Comment: @cachePut will rewrite cache with new value because the key is name of method and value is new object.